# Redirecting to another address

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have a page (done in CodeIgniter) associated with WordPress.
The blog has changed address:

From `example.com/wp` to `example.com/blog`

I want to other posts from the old address may appear at a new address, for example.: `example.com/blog?p=32`

I created a controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once LIBRARIES.'functions.inc';

class Wp extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect("/blog", "refresh");
    }

    public function _remap($method) {
        Remap($this, $method);
    }
}
```

But does not work.
What could be wrong?

Comment: use htaccess instead of CI redirect,`you are neglecting the parameters currently`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just [use .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)?